# Split string and numbers with dashes in python

Tags: python, split, numbers, arabic, arabic-support

I have two lists `chapter` and `verse`

The text that I'm trying to add to these lists are as follows:

"الشورى22-23", "السجدة44-55"

translated into "Alshoura22-23", "Alsadjah44-55"

The ouput should be:

`chapter` = ["الشورى", "السجدة"]

`verse` = ["22-23", "44-55"]

I tried many methods such as regression and iterate through each characters but to no avail! Could you please help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions provide a way to accomplish this goal.

```py
data = ["الشورى22-23", "السجدة44-55"]
verse = [re.findall(r'\d+\-\d+', s)[0] for s in data]
# ['22-23', '44-55']
chapter = [data[i].replace(verse[i], '') for i in range(len(verse))]
# ['الشورى', 'السجدة']
```

Comment: I didn't test, but shouldn't the output of the 1st operation be `['23-22', '55-44']` ?

Comment: Copied and pasted directly from my Python session. I'm assuming this has to do with the right-to-left nature of Arabic text.

Comment: If we make `data` `['55-44foo', '23-22bar']` then `verse` is `['55-44', '23-22']`.

Comment: @OsmanMamun like Chris said, because it's Arabic and it's right-to-left text

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print both ways, you can use a pattern with capture groups to match the allowed characters, and then add the right group to the right collection:

For the current example strings:

```
import re

lst = ["الشورى22-23", "السجدة44-55"]
pattern = r"([\u0600-\u06FF]+)(\d+-\d+)"
verse = []
chapter = []

for s in lst:
    m = re.match(pattern, s)
    if m:
        verse.append(m.group(1))
        chapter.append(m.group(2))

print(chapter)
print(verse)
```

Output

```
['22-23', '44-55']
['الشورى', 'السجدة']
```

For both combinations, check the capture group values:

```
import re

lst = ["الشورى22-23", "السجدة44-55", "11-22السجدة"]
pattern = r"([\u0600-\u06FF]+)(\d+-\d+)|(\d+-\d+)([\u0600-\u06FF]+)"
chapter = []
verse = []

for s in lst:
    for t in re.findall(pattern, s):
        chapter.append(t[1] if t[1] else t[2])
        verse.append(t[0] if t[0] else t[3])

print(chapter)
print(verse)
```

output

```
['22-23', '44-55', '11-22']
['الشورى', 'السجدة', 'السجدة']
```